# SQL - Compound index on inner join table?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, database-design

I'm trying to create additional index or indexes to speed up the query below. All the of the keys are primary keys (except for id on Table A) so they already have a default btree index associated with them. id on table A also has a index already associated with it since its a MUL key which means it's part of a non unique index.

```
Select A.id
From TableA A
      Inner join TableB B
      On A.address = B.address
      And A.code = B.code
Group by A.id
Having count(distinct B.user) = 1;
```

These are the current index on the mentioned tables:

```
mysql> show index from TableA;
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| TableA |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | address      | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| TableA |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | code         | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| TableA |         1  | id       |            1 | id           | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+


mysql> show index from TableB;
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| TableB    |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | user        | A         |           9 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| TableB    |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | address     | A         |           9 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| TableB    |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | code        | A         |           9 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| TableB    |          1 | address  |            1 | address     | A         |           9 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| TableB    |          1 | address  |            2 | code        | A         |           9 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

The query explain states this:

```
    +----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                   | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | F     | index  | address       | address | 514     | NULL                                  |    9 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 514     | db.B.address,db.B.code                |    1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I'm having trouble understanding what I should do. Is a compound index of address and code the only thing that I would be able to do to improve the speed of the mentioned query?

Or is a clustered index of id (since the query uses a group by) better? Or could I use both?

Comment: I think by *clustered index* you may mean *compound index*. Clustered indexes are a thing in SQL server but not in MySQL.

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY(address, code)` is both 'composite' (aka 'compound') and clustered.  In InnoDB, the PK is, by MySQL's definition, unique and clustered.

Comment: This is a dup of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158385/compound-index-on-inner-join-table , which has one Answer so far.

Comment: Please **do not cross-post**. Either flag for migration or close this question.

Answer (score 2):

As of late 2016, MySQL can't exploit more than one index for any given table in a single query. So, adding new single-column indexes doesn't help. I think you know that.

It's hard to know how well a compound index will work without trying it.  That being said, I suggest you try this index on `TableB`.  `(address, code, user)`?

Why? The query looks for particular values of `code` and `address`, then summarizes `user`.  Give it a try.

You could try a compound index on `TableA` as well. It would be `(id, address, code)`. This starts with `id` because you don't have any `WHERE` filters on `TableA`, and your `GROUP BY` clause can be optimized by scanning your table in `id` order. But try the `TableB` index first.

http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a good reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, actually I'm relatively new to databases and the concepts are still a bit hard to understand at the moment.

Comment: Since I have a group by instruction wouldn't it be advisable as well to have a clustered index for id on Table A?

Comment: Alternatively, rearrange your PK by putting `user` last.